# Help with probability problem

Tags: probability, statistics

I have to solve the following probability problem but I'm not sure how:

An electronics store is supplied with computers by three factories. From factory A obtains 30% from factory B 20% and from factory C 50% of the computers. It is known that the probability of a computer to be defective is 3%, 1% and 4% from factories A, B and C, respectively.

Find the probability of:

a) a computer is from A or not from B

b) a computer to be defective.

For a, I found 86% and I think it's correct but I don't know how to solve b.

Can someone help? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a probability tree, then add up all the outcomes where a computer is defective. A tree can be used to model many situtations, say a coin toss. In order to use it you will need to know the multiplicative and additive principles of probability(know when to multiply or add probabilities). Instead of drawing the tree, we can also just think of the cases where a computer fails.

Case 1: Computer is from factory A and fails

The probability of the computer being from factory A is 30%, and the probability of the computer failing given that it is from A is 3%. Since these both need to occure in order for this case to happen we multiply the probabilites: $P(\text{Case 1}) = 30\% \cdot 3 \%$

Case 2: Computer is from factory B and fails

Simillar to Case 1, we know the probability of the computer being from factory B and the probability of the computer failing given that it is from B, so we simply multiply them: $P(\text{Case 2}) = 20\% \cdot 1\% $

Case 3: Copmuter is from factory C and fails

Use the same logic as for Case 1 and Case 2, $P(\text{Case 3}) = 50\% \cdot 4\% $

These are all the different ways a computer can fail in this situtation(there are no other factories). Now all we have to do is add them up. Therefore
\begin{equation}
P(\text{fail}) = P(\text{Case 1}) + P(\text{Case 2}) + P(\text{Case 3}) = 30\% \cdot 3 \% + 20\% \cdot 1\% + 50\% \cdot 4\%
\end{equation} 
Evaulating this expression will yield the answer

Comment: I don't know this method. Could you please show me how to solve it?

Comment: Sorry @iadvd, but for some reason it keeps saying I need 50 reputation to comment on his post. And George, I have edited my answer to contain a solution.

Comment: @Jeevan now that you converted the comment into an explanation should be fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

For B)
Here at the main points:

Factory A has 30% of computers with a defective rate of 3%.

Factory B has 50% of computers with defective rate of 1%

Factory C has 20% of computers defective of 4%.

Comment: I don't understand how these info lead to the answer. What do i have to do next to find the probability of one computer to be defective?

Comment: @George A computer is defective if: it is defective and from A, or it is defective and from B, or it is defective and from C.  Now as you know $3\%\times 30\%$ of the computers are defective and from A, and so forth, then...